# How to execute ubuntu.exe and navigate to direct folder with one command?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 10 OS.
I'm want to setup phpstorm terminal to use ubuntu.exe "terminal".
When i change it - terminal opens "home" directory for current linux user.
I want to navigate to my certain folder "/var/www/" when terminal inits.
Maybe i should use some flags like this?

```
 .../ubuntu.exe -e "cd /var/www"
```

Answer (score 1):

So i created bat file with content:

```
C:\Users\Art4es\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe run /bin/bash
```

Then in phpstorm: Settings>Tools>Terminal in 'Shell path' field insert path to this bat file.
Now terminal 'knows' project's directory path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings>Tools>Terminal*, make sure "Start directory" is set to the desired path:

```
C:\<path_to_ubuntu_filesystem>\var\www
```

Set "Sell path":

```
C:\<path_to_ubuntu_executable>\ubuntu.exe run
```